# Tokens in a bag

Tags: algorithm, proof, induction

We have n tokens. Every token is either red, blue, or green. These n tokens are in a bag

Repeat the following until the bag is empty:

1) If there are more than two tokens in the bag. take two random tokens out of the bag. Otherwise, empty the bag.

2) According to the two tokens we got in step 1), we do the following things:

∗ Case 1: If one of the tokens is red, do nothing.

∗ Case 2: If both tokens are green, we put one green token and 2 blue tokens back
into the bag.

∗ Case 3: If we got one blue token, and the other token is not red, then we put 3
red tokens back into the bag.

Assume that we always have enough tokens to put back into the bag, prove via induction that this process always terminates.

---

So for my base case, I put n = 1 and since we have less than 2 tokens, we just empty the bag and the process terminates.

I don't know where to go from there.

This is what I've written down in my notebook just thinking about the problem:

R = red, B = blue, G = green

If we take out RR, we do nothing and the bag now contains n=n-2 tokens

If we take out RB, we do nothing and the bag now contains n=n-2 tokens

If we take out RG, we do nothing and the bag now contains n=n-2 tokens

If we take out BB, we put 3 red tokens back in and now the bag contains +1 token (since we took out 2 and added 3 back)

If we take out BG, do the same as above

If we take out GG, 1 green and 2 blue goes back in and now the bag contains +1 token

What I think I can see from this is that eventually, the bag will be full or almost full with red tokens since there is only one situation where we put tokens back in that are not red and two situations where we put back 3 red tokens. And whenever we pull out a red token, we do nothing and just shrink the token size in the bag until the bag is empty.

The amount of green tokens will shrink relative to the amount of blue and red tokens. We want to pull a red or blue token, not so much with green.

I'm not sure how to prove this via induction. Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT: Thanks I think I got it now

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint.  Instead of red, blue and green think pennies, dimes and quarters.  Proceed by induction on the value of what is in the bag.

Answer (score 1):

You have these three rules:

1. If one of the tokens is red, do nothing.
2. If both tokens are green, we put one green token and 2 blue tokens back into the bag.
3. If we got one blue token, and the other token is not red, then we put 3 red tokens back into the bag.

Going from there:

1. Assume you have two green tokens in the bag. You pull both of them. One green token goes back in. The number of green tokens is decreased by 1. In the worst case, you'll put one green token into the bag for every two that you take out. You will *always* run out of green tokens.
2. Whenever you pull GG, you add two blue tokens to the bag. But point #1 says that you will always run out of green, and therefore you won't be able to add more blue. After that, whenever you pull a blue token, it stays out of the bag.
3. Every red token you pull out stays out unless you pull a BG or BB. But point #2 says you'll run out of blue, at which point no more reds can go into the bag.

You'll have to write it up into a formal proof by induction, but that's the basic approach.

Comment: Point 1 is only true if you can prove that you will eventually wind up pulling another green token.  If the number of other tokens in the bag keeps staying the same or increasing, this isn't guaranteed to happen.  And the last operation increases that number.  So unless the induction argument for point 1 is very, very carefully written, it will have a flaw in it.  By contrast my value suggestion leads to a straightforward formal proof with strong induction - the value of what is in the bag is always decreasing.  Eventually the bag runs out of money.

Comment: To get a correct formal proof along your lines you actually have to reverse your three arguments and do 3 separate induction proofs.  First prove by induction on the number of reds that you must eventually pull something non-red out or run out.  Then by induction on the number of blues that you must eventually pull a green out or run out.  Then by induction on the number of greens that you eventually run out.

Comment: @btilly Although I agree that your value suggestion is a superior idea. My answer is not a great method of induction, now that I think about it more. But it does have value. You're right that the proof for point #1 would have to be worded carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is by induction on the number of green tokens in the bag.
Base case: when there are no green tokens in the bag initially, there will never be green tokens in the bag, since no rule adds any. In this case, no rule adds blue tokens, and we can only remove finitely many red tokens before being forced to remove all blue tokens which cannot be replaced. Then, all red tokens must be removed.

Induction hypothesis: for all initial configurations with up to and including k green tokens, the process eventually terminates.

Induction step: we must show the process halts for all initial configurations with k+1 green tokens. There are 6 cases for the first draw:
1. Red/Red - the reds are removed and we remain in the same k+1 greens situation. This can only happen finitely many times before another case must be encountered.
2. Red/Green - the red and green are removed and we now have k green tokens remaining; we know from the induction hypothesis that the process terminates from this point.
3. Red/Blue - the red and blue are removed and we remain in the same k+1 greens situation. This can only happen finitely many times before another case must be encountered.
4. Green/Green - two greens are removed, giving a k-1 case. By the induction hypothesis, we know the process terminates from this point.
5. Green/Blue - one green is removed so we are now in the k  greens situation. We know the process terminates from this point by the hypothesis.
6. Blue/Blue - two blues are removed. This can only happen finitely many times before another situation is encountered.

Crucially: cases 1, 3 and 6 cannot form a closed loop since none of these add blue tokens. Therefore, these cases as a whole can only occur a finite number of times before one of the other cases must be encountered; since cases 2, 4 and 5 give a configuration from which the process terminates by the induction hypothesis, all starting configurations with k+1 green tokens must terminate.

Note: if you have R red, G green and B blue tokens in the bag, how many draws can you do in the worst case before you are guaranteed to have to draw a green? The worst case is you draw B/2 double blues until exhausted, producing 1.5B extra red tokens, and then draw (R+1.5B)/2 pairs of red tokens until exhausted, for a total of (R+2.5B)/2 draws. This means that you must eventually draw a green, permanently reducing the number of greens available to draw, no matter the bag configuration, initial or otherwise. Since the number of green tokens is finite, non-negative and decreasing, the process must terminate.